# Loadrunner if LR_Fail exclude from write to file

Tags: web, automation, transactions, performance-testing, loadrunner

Okay so I am attempting to create a utility script that will generate a bunch of users for my testing purposes. If the script **passes** I need the output to write to a file. Like this

At the end of the script action, if the transaction -

```
 lr_end_transaction("Util_02_MemberReg_04_Step2", LR_AUTO);
```

is a pass, then move to the

```
lr_output_message("Writing to file = %s", filename);
```

However this is working I need it to exclude any transaction that is an LR_Fail. Right now it is write to my file if it passes or fails.

What I need to know is if there is a way to exclude LR_Fail from the write to command?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: lr_get_transaction_status() .  You're going to have a wait for exclusive lock problem if you have multiple users writing to the same file.  Consider a process which writes that information to a queue for all users, then a single virtual user to write to a file.

Comment: Also, if this continues through your large scale testing, your write to disk will become a drag anchor for all of your virtual user processes....slowing....wating for lock...writing....releasing lock....  You can observe the difference just by upping the log level for all of your users to observe how much slower they run having to write logs to the drive